# Script error: Object does not support property or method in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2005

I just created a simple MFC dialog based application in VS2005. Whenever I am trying to **add variable** to an **edit control** I am getting this error.

I am new in MFC. Please help me fix this :(
Using: C++98 with VS2005

[image: Script error message]

Comment: Why bother with wizard, given how long it's going to take you to sort this out just add the code manually yourself. It's probably a problem with the version of IE you have, I remember various similar issues with VS2005.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add any variable(control/value) to any of your control and fortunately you deleted it?

If so, you have to remove the ID for control in resources.h and app.rc and also variable initialized in .h files and used in your cpp files.

It may also cause this problem. But im not sure.

Comment: No No. This did not happen :( I have made new applications from scratch and still having this problem :(